# Custom auth handler with mechanize

Tags: python, mechanize

I would like to use [python-ntlm](http://code.google.com/p/python-ntlm/) with mechanize.Browser() I have got HTTPNtlmAuthHandler working with urllib2 and mechanize.urlopen() and tried to use it with Browser() but it doesn't work

Here is the code I'm using for urlopen

```
passman = mechanize.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
passman.add_password(None, url, user, password)
auth_NTLM = HTTPNtlmAuthHandler.HTTPNtlmAuthHandler(passman)

opener = mechanize.build_opener(auth_NTLM)
mechanize.install_opener(opener)
mechanize.urlopen(baseurl)
```

**Traceback as requested**

```
harrisony@lithium:~$ python sitefoo.py 
now running mechanize.urlopen
<addinfourl at 169181868 whose fp = <httplib.HTTPResponse instance at 0xa15858c>>


now running mechanize.Browser then br.open
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sitescreaper.py", line 21, in <module>
    br.open(baseurl)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 209, in open
    return self._mech_open(url, data, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mechanize/_mechanize.py", line 261, in _mech_open
    raise response
mechanize._response.httperror_seek_wrapper: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized
```

Comment: Do you get an error? If so, please add the exception traceback to your question.

Answer (score 1):

There may be better options, but the only way I could get it to work was to remove the HTTPRobotRulesProcessor handler which was somehow preventing the HTTPNtlmAuthHandler from being called.

Note:  The following code also happens to remove the ProxyHandler in order to bypass the proxy server - remove if applicable.

```
passman = mechanize.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
passman.add_password(None, baseurl, user, password)
auth_NTLM = HTTPNtlmAuthHandler.HTTPNtlmAuthHandler(passman)

browser = mechanize.Browser()
browser.add_handler(auth_NTLM)

handlersToKeep = []
for handler in browser.handlers:
    if not isinstance(handler, (mechanize._auth.ProxyHandler, 
                                mechanize._urllib2_support.HTTPRobotRulesProcessor)):
        handlersToKeep.append(handler)
browser.handlers = handlersToKeep

browser.open(url)
```